# Trying to print something when two objects are in contact/collides. Will later add score when ball touches the bottom of the bucket

Tags: swift, collision-detection, scenekit, arkit

My two objects are: a ball, and a bucket. The bucket consists of two childNode[image: Torus which is the upper part and cylinder the base at the bottom of the bucket] What I am trying to achieve is to do something whenever the ball goes inside the bucket and touches the "cylinder" of the bucket which is the base. But when I add the baseNode as childNode with name cylinder, my bucket disappears in the scene and does not load anything. How can I get this working along with the contact that is happening.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

enum BodyType: Int{

case ballNode = 1
case baseNode = 2

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {






@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!



@IBOutlet weak var AddBasketBtn: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

sceneView.scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self as? SCNPhysicsContactDelegate


    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self

    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true

    // Create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()

    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView.scene = scene



   registerGestureRecognizer()
}



func registerGestureRecognizer(){


  let directions : [UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction] = [.up]
    for direction in directions{
   let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe))
    swipe.direction = direction
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)

    }

}


@objc func handleSwipe(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    //print ("will it work?")
    //sceneview to be accessed
    //access the point of view of the sceneView, the center point

    guard let sceneView = gestureRecognizer.view as? ARSCNView else{

        return
    }
    guard let centerPoint = sceneView.pointOfView else {

        return

    }

    //transform matrix
    //the orientation
    //position of camera
    // orientation and position are needed to determine the camera where the ball needs to be placed
    let cameraTransform = centerPoint.transform

    let cameraLocation = SCNVector3(x: cameraTransform.m41, y: cameraTransform.m42, z: cameraTransform.m43)

    let cameraOrientation = SCNVector3(x: -cameraTransform.m31, y: -cameraTransform.m32, z: -cameraTransform.m33)

    //x1 + x2, y1+y2, z1+z2
    let cameraPosition = SCNVector3Make(cameraLocation.x + cameraOrientation.x, cameraLocation.y + cameraOrientation.y, cameraLocation.z + cameraOrientation.z)

    let ball = SCNSphere(radius:0.04)
   // Bucketnode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.2,0.2,0.2);
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "basketballSkin.png")
    ball.materials = [material]

    let ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: ball)

    ballNode.position = cameraPosition

    let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: ballNode, options:nil)

    let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: physicsShape)

    ballNode.physicsBody = physicsBody

    ballNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ballNode.rawValue
    ballNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.ballNode.rawValue
    ballNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.ballNode.rawValue

    let forceVector:Float = 2.7

    ballNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3Make(cameraPosition.x * forceVector, cameraPosition.y * forceVector, cameraPosition.z*forceVector), asImpulse: true)


    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { // change 2 to desired number of seconds
        ballNode.removeFromParentNode()
    }
}

func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.nodeA.categoryBitMask | contact.nodeB.categoryBitMask
    switch (contactMask) {
    case BodyType.baseNode.rawValue | BodyType.ballNode.rawValue :
        print("hit")
    default:
        return
    }
}


func addBackboard(){


guard let bucketScene = SCNScene(named:"art.scnassets/BucketBlue.scn") else {

    return
}

guard let bucketNode = bucketScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "tube", recursively: false) else {

    return
}

guard let baseNode = bucketScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "cylinder", recursively: true) else {

    return
} //this part makes my bucket disappear, without it, it works fine but no contact action can be recognised

baseNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.baseNode.rawValue
baseNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.baseNode.rawValue
baseNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.baseNode.rawValue

bucketNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.15,0.15,0.15);
bucketNode.worldPosition = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -1.35, z: -1.4)


let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: bucketNode, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron])

let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: physicsShape)

bucketNode.physicsBody = physicsBody

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(bucketNode)

}



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Create a session configuration
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    // Run the view's session
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Pause the view's session
    sceneView.session.pause()
}

// MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate

/*
// Override to create and configure nodes for anchors added to the view's session.
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    let node = SCNNode()

    return node
}
*/

func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    // Present an error message to the user

}

func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
    // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay

}

func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
    // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required

}
@IBAction func AddBasket(_ sender: Any) {
    addBackboard()
    AddBasketBtn.isHidden = true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in my code by deleting the base of the bucket in SceneKit editor and then adding another base to it through code using SCNCylinder as a new node to the scene. Then I used the new node for contact with my ball using contact bit masks.

Answer (score 1):

Few things, first is ARKit space is measured in meters so keep it in mind while placing the objects, second you're not really making use of ARkit (maybe will use it later, ok) but if that's your plan perhaps good to use an anchor to create a scnnode and then place your bucket on top of the anchor:

Next code mainly comes from Apple's developer site.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
// Place content only for anchors found by plane detection.
guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

// Create a SceneKit plane to visualize the plane anchor using its position and extent.
let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z))
let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
planeNode.simdPosition = float3(planeAnchor.center.x, 0, planeAnchor.center.z)

// `SCNPlane` is vertically oriented in its local coordinate space, so
// rotate the plane to match the horizontal orientation of `ARPlaneAnchor`.
planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

// Make the plane visualization semitransparent to clearly show real-world placement.
planeNode.opacity = 0.25

// Add the plane visualization to the ARKit-managed node so that it tracks
// changes in the plane anchor as plane estimation continues.
node.addChildNode(planeNode)

node.addChildNode(bucketNode)
```

}

So you´d first allow ARKit to create the anchor and then place the SCNPlane and after that you will see your bucket right in the middle of the SCNPlane (just don't set any position to your bucket).

Finally position the SCNTorus somewhere like float3(0.0,0.20,0.0) this is 20 cms. above the center of the anchor

Comment: Okay I will try that once I get home. But then how about the contact between the two objects?

Comment: The ball can be added as a child of the bucket